# protect docker container and\or volume from accidental deletion

Tags: docker, docker-volume, data-protection

we have a docker container (mongodb) we are using, with volume mount to store data persistently.

I would like to protect the container and\or volume from accidental deletion by commands 'docker volume prune' or even just 'docker volume rm'

any suggestion?

Comment: A hacky way would be `chattr +i /path/to/docker/volume/on/host`

Comment: Secure your docker engine correctly, only give access to entitled and capable ops, and make regular backups. @Robert unless I missed something, your solution would also prevent the volume from being written to (which is probably quite annoying for a db).

Comment: @Zeitounator - it's myself I'm afraid of. :\

Answer (score 3):

Create a function / alias in the bash profile or bashrc.

```
function docker {
  docker_vol_res="Y"
  [[ $1 == vol* ]] && [[ $2 == prune || $2 == rm ]] && echo -n "Do you want to \"$2\" the volume (Y/N)? " && read docker_vol_res
  [[ $docker_vol_res == "Y" ]] && /usr/bin/docker $*
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To prevent accidental deletion of container/volume, there is no any in-built way provided by docker for it.

Check [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9878) out.

Also there was a code change to have this feature as mentioned [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9878#issuecomment-68568837) but it was voted against by solomon hykes because of few [reasons](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/7523#issuecomment-59592874).

---

But there is way to prevent accidental volume deletion while using `docker volume prune`.

Check [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9878#issuecomment-338218409) out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. I am reading about how I can apply prune filters. seems I can configure only by creating a $HOME/.docker/config.json file (meaning configure per user). is there a way to have a config file like that for all users?

Comment: @GKman https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files this should help.